# How to get screen resolution with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, screen-resolution

I need get screen resolution with node.js, but the following code don't work.

```
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
```

This also don't work.

```
var w = window.screen.width;
var h = window.screen.height;
```

Someone know how to get screen resolution with node.js ?
Thank you.

Comment: What if the server isn't running a graphical interface, which is most likely the case?

Comment: Why would it be a server?

Comment: Because Node.js doesn't run client side, it runs on the server.

Comment: Joe, in this case i'm sure that user have a GUI

Comment: "Nodejs doesn't run on the client side" - is silly an untrue. That's like saying "Java doesn't run on the client side". [ElectronJs](https://electronjs.org/) and a host of other technologies all run nodejs on workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with `phantomJS`.

Install `phantomJS`:

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

Create app.js file:

```
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;

console.log(w+"x"+h);

phantom.exit();
```

Execute:

```
phantomjs app.js
```

Return:

```
1366x768
```

Answer (score 5):

There is now a screenres module via npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenres

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` in your client-side JavaScript code and send that information to your server-side Node.js application via AJAX, WebSocket, as form data, etc.

For example:

```
(function(w) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json',
        data: {
            w: w.screen.width,
            h: w.screen.height
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
})(window);
```

This is common and is not related to the server-side technology. Doesn't matter what you use at the back-end (Node.js, Python, Ruby, PHP, Java, ASP.NET, etc.), you should send a data from client to server since the server doesn't deal with the user's browser directly.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but i want get screen resolution of the server same.

Comment: If you run a browser on the server you can run the client-side script in that browser and send the data to the server-side application in same way.

Comment: In the common case of Linux servers running multiple displays, X11 defaults internally to a single huge aggregate window. Phantomjs will return that resolution. Eugene's answer will return the resolution of whatever display the browser is running on, regardless of OS, or how its window manager is configured.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an overkill, but the node module I found doesn't work anymore and it doesn't handle multiple displays anyway:

```
npm install nightmare
```

And then if you want for exampnle the size and coordinates of the external monitor if available:

```
const getBounds = async () => {
  const nm = new Nightmare({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  const bounds = nm
    .goto('about:blank')
    .evaluate(() => {
      const electron = require('electron');
      const displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays()
      const display = displays.find((d) => d.bounds.x !== 0 || d.bounds.y !== 0) || displays[0];
      return display.bounds;
    }).end();
  return bounds;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [screenz](https://github.com/Richienb/screenz):

```js
const { width, height } = require("screenz");

console.log(width);
//=> 1920

console.log(height);
//=> 1080
```

Comment: This entire module is just 
```
const robot = require("robotjs")
module.exports = robot.getScreenSize()
```
And robotjs does not support multi-monitor btw.

Comment: @Arbiter How would you like it to handle multi-monitor support?

Comment: I would like it to tell me the number of monitors and the widths and heights of each monitor?