# How to get the display count/resolution from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, screen-resolution

I understand it's a backend server, but since people are building cross system client apps with it, I thought it was worth asking.

Is there a simple way of getting information about display count and their resolutions from nodejs? I mean the computer on which node runs, not client Web browsers.

I'll accept a Mac solution if cross system is impossible.

Comment: read the system information and invoke it from node code.

Comment: @akonsu - yeah, I imagined someone already did the hard work to make it cross-system :)

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989295/how-to-get-screen-resolution-with-node-js

Answer (score 2):

This is totally platform dependent. On OS X you can utilize Quartz Display Services API for that. If you're interested, I've start a package for that: https://github.com/vkurchatkin/quartz-display-services.

It's pretty raw now and the only thing it can do is returning array of displays with pixel dimensions:

```
var services = require('./index.js');

services.displays().forEach(function (display) {
  console.log(display);
});
```

yields:

```
{ width: 1280, height: 800 }
```

on my Mac Pro. Obviously need to test it with multi-display setup)